# RL with ns3-gym for fuzz testing

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, fuzzing

Is there a way to use [ns3-gym](https://github.com/tkn-tub/ns3-gym) for fuzz testing? ns3-gym is used for networking, but recently people are using it for cognitive radio and other things as well. I am trying to use RL to improve code coverage during fuzz testing and I thought ns3-gym could be a good module for this, but I fail to find good examples or repos that at least give me a good start. Any hints or ideas are appreciated. Thanks